# Showing an AdMob "rewarded" ad using Delphi

Tags: delphi, admob, firemonkey

I am looking to reward my Android game's players by giving them the option to display a "rewarded" ad (see https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) for in-game features.

Unfortunately, I can't find any reference on how to do it using the latest version of Delphi.

I searched the web and found bits and pieces that were either partial, discontinued or possibly incompatible with the latest version of Delphi.

I found this article discussing Interstitial ads and in the comments section there's some discussion of Rewarded ads being accessible using Aerserv integration:
http://www.danielespinetti.it/2015/04/how-to-use-admob-interstitial-ads-with.html

However, since the 2015 joint announcement between Aerserv and Embarcadero, I couldn't find the actual components, not on Aerserv's website, not on the GetIt service and not in any web searches.

In summation, how can I show AdMob Rewarded ads using the latest version of Delphi (currently 10.2.3)?